# Filtering the tibble based on a column that contains more than one values

Tags: r, string, list, dataframe, filter

I am trying to filter a tibble to the rows where it contains a certain value in a column.
However, this column has more than one values that are separated by a ";".

For example,

```
  A       
 <chr>    
1 "this; is; one; value"
2 "this; is; another"
```

Let's say I want to filter this tibble and get the rows where at least one of the words is "one". However, I couldn't find a way to do so.

I tried to split these values based on ;, unlist them, and then check but it didn't work.
My code was something like:

```
tibble %>% 
 filter(unlist(str_split(A, ";")) == "one")
```

But this raised an error. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the tidyverse we could use `stringr::str_detect` inside `dplyr::filter`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

tibble(A = c("this; is; one; value", "this; is; another")) %>% 
         filter(str_detect(A, "one"))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 1
#>   A                   
#>   <chr>               
#> 1 this; is; one; value
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

And in base R we can do:

```r
dat <- data.frame(A = c("this; is; one; value", "this; is; another")) 
subset(dat, grepl("one", A))
#>                      A
#> 1 this; is; one; value
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert in R, but I guess you could just do:

```
filter(df, str_detect(df$A, "one;"))
```

Output:

```
                       A
1 1 this; is; one; value
```